Visual Studio Code: Cannot find support for specifying a custom attribute should be a url value for path completion
I am aware of the custom data feature for extending the defintions for vscode html-language service. However, from the schema definitions there doesn't seem to be a way to specify an attribute is a url value (similar to how href, url(), src attributes are treated).
I want to know if there is a solution for this. P.S: there's a 5 year still open issue that references this: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-html-languageservice/issues/76
reference page for html-language custom data: https://code.visualstudio.com/blogs/2020/02/24/custom-data-format
I have tried adding a custom tag and attribute to vscode settings but the schema definitions do not support passing a type property in the attribute description object
